# Asp.net-Run a global method after session time outing or browser closing

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables, session-state

I using the sessions to be online users in my project asp,C# web site, but for view offline my members i have some problem: 
following option to user can be offline:
1: user can push Sign out button: this is well working because i adding this user session id to offline users table in database by code behind   
**2: close browser :** this is my problem that how can i adding the session id in to offline users table in database
**3: session timeout after 15 minuet:** this is my problem too how can i adding this session id in to offline users table in  database

Comment: Why do you wish to track that someone is offline?

Comment: i designed a page to see all of my site members with there situation, i using session to know valid user after login in own account . its well . but how can i shown the offline members? or when users close browser and session time out evened, after that what can i do?

Comment: The short answer is - this is hard. You could achieve it by having JS on the page to periodically ping back to the server 'the browser is still open'. I would strongly suggest you reconsider the need for this requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to handle the `Signout`with the javascript function if the user closes the browser.

You can do this with [onunload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp) and [onbeforeunload](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp)

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onunload = function()
{
   //code for signout by ajax calling the server method, or just 
document.getElementById("Signout_Button").click();
}

</script>
```

Comment: Where can i call this script for close browser? please guide me with detail

Comment: @aram `window.onunload` function will be called automatically when the browser get closed